# Google maps ios not showing the routes exact in road

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Google maps ios -  not showing the routes exactly its far away from the road for long route maps.

[image]

Code used for showing path:

```
- (void)addDirections:(NSDictionary *)json {

    if ([json objectForKey:@"routes"]) {
        if ([[json objectForKey:@"routes"] count] > 0) {
            NSDictionary *routes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"][0];

            NSDictionary *route = [routes objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
            NSString *overview_route = [route objectForKey:@"points"];
            GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:overview_route];
            GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
            polyline.map = mapView_;
            polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            polyline.strokeWidth = 10.f;
            polyline.geodesic = YES;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Which Map are you using for showing the route? Google Map or iOS map.

Comment: I have mentioned - Its google maps

Comment: Where does your `points` come from? there are 2 possibility.. 1) your receiver used different kind of encoding system, which makes them provide a different values for the same point on earth; 2) poor data, in this case, you can use [Google Maps Road API's Snap to Roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) function to correct your data

Comment: @kaho -  Is this we can use in iOS apps?

Comment: You should be able to do that, since the road API is a restful api. perhaps you can refer to this regarding on how to call restful api https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-ios/